# Conversion to another Datatype

Tags: haskell, types

I have the following datatypes:

```
data Food = Butter Int | Apple Int Food | Meat Double Food deriving (Show)

data Basket = Basket { butter, apple :: Int, meat :: (Int,Double) } deriving (Show)
```

Basket contains the amount of butter and apples, the amount of meat and its overall weight(as Double).

I'm trying to write a function **food2basket :: Food -> Basket** that allows me to convert a value of the type Food into a value of the type Basket.

So if I declared this instance of Food:

```
     andrew = Apple 1 ( Meat 0.60 ( Meat 0.70 ( Apple 1 ( Butter 1 ))))
```

By applying the function I'd get the following result

```
 food2basket andrew == {butter = 1, apple= 2, meat = (2,1.30)}
```

So far my code looks like:

```
emptyBasket = Basket {butter = 0, apple= 0, meat = (0,0)}
food2basket (Butter i)      = emptyBasket {butter = i}
food2basket (Apple i b)     = anotherBasket{apple = i + (apple anotherBasket)}
    where anotherBasket     = food2basket b
food2basket (Meat d b)      = auxFood (Meat d b) 0
    where
         auxFood(Meat d b) n= emptyBasket { meat = (n+1,d)} -- missing recursion
```

It is working up to "Apple" part, even tough I found it difficult to use recursion inside the brackets. That's why I used anotherBasket and the where-clause, which is quite confusing.
As feared I can't manage to do the same with Meat. (It does no recursion (yet))

I'd like to resolve the whole function with pattern matching.

Comment: Where is `auxFood` defined?  And the syntax `(Meat d b) n = ...` isn't valid.  What is `n` supposed to be here?

Comment: I forgot auxFood, it's in now. N is supposed to be the counter that  increases by 1 every time "meat" has been found(in the recursion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a more complete solution:

```
addBaskets :: Basket -> Basket -> Basket
addBaskets b1 b2 =
    Basket (butter b1 + butter b2) (apple b1 + apple b2) ((m1 + m2), (w1 + w2))
    where (m1, w1) = meat b1
          (m2, w2) = meat b2

food2basket :: Food -> Basket
food2basket (Butter x)  = emptyBasket { butter = x }
food2basket (Apple x f) = addBaskets emptyBasket { apple = x } (food2basket f)
food2basket (Meat x f)  = addBaskets emptyBasket { meat = (1, x) } (food2basket f)
```

Comment: Give a man food, and he eats for a day... [Sorry, no relevance here, I just had to. ;-) ]

Comment: Hehe, right...but he's probably been thinking about this one for a while.  Now that he knows the last step, that still probably helps with the learning process.  Sorry to poach the answer, by the way.

Answer (score 3):

The code looks a little bit confused. What you *might* want to do is define a function that adds two baskets together:

```
addBaskets b1 b2 = Basket {butter = butter b1 + butter b2, apple = ...
```

And then you could do something like

```
food2basket (Butter i)   = emptyBasket {butter = i}
food2basket (Apple  i b) = addBaskets (emptyBasket {apple = i}) (food2basket b)
food2basket (Meat   i b) = addBaskets (emptyBasket {meat  = i}) (food2basket b)
```

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on MathematicalOrchid's answer, this pattern looks a lot like a `Monoid`:

```
import Data.Monoid

instance Monoid Basket where
    mempty = Basket 0 0 (0, 0)  -- Same as emptyBasket
    mappend (Basket b1 a1 (m1, d1)) (Basket b2 a2 (m2, d2))
        = Basket (b1 + b2) (a1 + a2) (m1 + m2, d1 + d2)
```

And if you instead wrote your `Food` type as

```
data FoodItem
    = Butter Int
    | Apple Int
    | Meat Double
    deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Then you could have

```
type Food = [FoodItem]

foodItemToBasket :: FoodItem -> Basket
foodItemToBasket (Butter i) = mempty { butter = i }
foodItemToBasket (Apple  i) = mempty { apple = i }
foodItemToBasket (Meat   d) = mempty { meat = (1, d) }
```

Then you can simply use `map foodItemToBasket` and `mconcat`:

```
foodToBasket :: Food -> Basket
foodToBasket = mconcat . map foodItemToBasket
```

Now the conversion of each item to a basket it much simpler and doesn't contain recursion, and the act of combining these baskets together is handled by `mconcat`, a more generic function provided by `Data.Monoid`.

However, if you do want a recursive data structure you can actually seriously overcomplicate things by turning to the `Free` monad.  I'll gloss over the details, but it lets you do this (you need `DeriveFunctor` to compile this):

```
data FoodF f
    = Butter' Int
    | Apple' Int f
    | Meat' Double f
    deriving (Functor, Show)

type Food' = Free FoodF

butter' :: Int -> Food' ()
butter' i = liftF $ Butter' i

apple' :: Int -> Food' ()
apple' i = liftF $ Apple' i ()

meat' :: Double -> Food' ()
meat' d = liftF $ Meat' d ()

food'ToBasket :: Food' () -> Basket
food'ToBasket (Free (Butter' i)) = mempty { butter = i }
food'ToBasket (Free (Apple' i f)) = mempty { apple = i } <> food'ToBasket f
food'ToBasket (Free (Meat'  d f)) = mempty { meat = (1, d)} <> food'ToBasket f
food'ToBasket (Pure ()) = mempty

andrew :: Food' ()
andrew = do
    apple' 1
    meat' 0.6
    meat' 0.7
    apple' 1
    butter' 1
```

And now you can do

```
> food'ToBasket andrew
Basket { butter = 1, apple = 2, meat = (2, 1.2999999999998)}
```

(The imprecise weight is due to IEEE floating point format rounding errors, information on this is scattered all over the internet)

Why you would want to go this route is silly, I just thought it was interesting that your definition of `Food` fit the pattern to do this.  It does give you a nice monad instance for free that lets you simply list the different items a person has using do notation and then `food'ToBasket` handles "interpreting" this monad structure into a basket.  It does mean that something like

```
> food'ToBasket (butter' 1 >> apple' 1 >> meat' 0.5)
Basket { butter = 1, apple = 0, meat = (0, 0.0)}
```

So instead of having a compile-time check that `Butter'` is the last item in the structure you essentially have short-circuiting whenever `Butter'` is encountered, just like `Nothing` will short-circuit a `Maybe` computation.

Comment: Yeah, this makes more sense.  The original poster's representation of food orders is confusing.

Comment: Nice one, I'm not good with monoids so I was limiting myself with pattern matching & recursion. I didn't know how to call a recursion since I had to "obey" to a certain Type.

Comment: @user3086819 My intention with this answer was to provide you with more information about the general structure of your problem, not to serve as a complete solution to exactly what you had.  I figured it was pretty likely that the type `Food` was given to you to work with, but I wanted to highlight that it would make more sense to use a different data structure and utilize some of the more generic features of Haskell to solve the problem instead of rolling your own solution.  I had plenty of exercises like that at uni myself, I just find them to be counterproductive to good design.